# Problema con CSS para timeline

Tags: css, sass

Descargué un *timeline* de esta web https://codepen.io/P233/pen/lGewF pero tengo un problemita, no puedo modificar los círculos de la izquierda que acompañan a los botones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Veo un código así:

```
.radio:checked + .relative .circle {
    background: #f98262;
}
```

Pero no logro modificar el color del círculo, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si descargaste todo como viene en el ejemplo, simplemente tienes que buscar la clase del `<input>` la cual es `radio`.

Buscas en el scss el .radio y verás el siguiente código:

```
.radio
  display: none
.radio:checked
  & + .relative
    label
      cursor: auto
      @if $vertical
        transform: translateX(42px)
      @else
        width: 400px
        transition: width 0.3s linear 0.2s
    .circle
      background: $red
  & ~ .content
    max-height: 180px
    border-color: $white
    @if $vertical
      margin-right: 20px
      transform: translateX(20px)
      transition: max-height 0.4s linear, border-color 0.5s linear, transform 0.2s linear
    @else
      width: 400px
    p
      max-height: 200px
      color: $white
      transition: color 0.3s linear 0.3s
```

Como puedes ver el `.circle` tiene `background: $red`, simplemente cambia el valor de esa variable o pon un color directamente.